# How to center two divs floating next to one another

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have written the following HTML trying to center two div's next to each other.

```
<div id='wrapper' style='text-align:center;'>
    <div style='float:left;'>
        Lorem ipsum<br />
        dolor sit amet
    </div>
    <div style='float:left;'>
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    dolor sit amet
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the code I've written results in the two div's floating all the way to the left.  What this does do correctly is float the two div's side by side.

What do I need to change to center the two div's side by side?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You will have to automatically set the margin and probably a specific width to your wrapper div

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

In your CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I sort of understand what you're saying; but why does 'margin' have two values?

Comment: Basically margin can have up to four values setting [top, right, bottom, left]. With two values you set the [top-bottom, left-right] margin (setting left-right to auto causes it to center) with only one value you set the same margin for every side.

Comment: I've had exactly the same problem and I've tried your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/6ARJX/9/ Didn't work for me, though. Any suggestion?

Comment: Well you set your container width to 100%. Try setting it to e.g. 80% and the outside div will be centered.

Answer (score 42):

Instead of using `float: left`, use `display: inline-block`:

```
<div id='wrapper' style='text-align: center;'>
    <div style='display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;'>
        Lorem ipsum<br />
        dolor sit amet,<br />
        consectetur adipisicing elit
    </div>
    <div style='display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;'>
        Lorem ipsum<br />
        dolor sit amet
    </div>
</div>
```

The top of each inner `div` is kept aligned by using `vertical-align: top`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hCV8f/1/

Comment: `display: inline-block` is not always working, but its the first thing you need to check.

Comment: It will work. Just make sure that the left and right div's contents are not too large, otherwise they will fall one below the other. One example. If the right section has a lot of text, give it a fixed width to have the text wrapped.

Comment: This is great.  You may want to add `vertical-align:top` to the item divs.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
<div id='wrapper' style='text-align:center;'>
    <div style='float:left;background-color:red;width:50%'>
        Lorem ipsum<br />dolor sit amet
    </div>
    <div style='float:right;background-color:blue;width:50%'>
         Lorem ipsum<br />dolor sit amet
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JDAyt/

Comment: +1 for simplicity. `float:left` and `float:right` values are all that are needed without the extra wrapping and css.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know the width of both `div`s in advance? If so, you can just do something like

```
<div class="wrapper" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 200px">
  <div class="inner1" style="width: 100px; float:left;"></div>
  <div class="inner2" style="width: 100px; margin-left: 100px"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below worked for me

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div class='inner'>
        content 1
    </div>
    <div class='inner'>
        content 2
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper
{
text-align: center;width:auto;margin:0 auto
}
.inner
{
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: The .wrapper in the CSS should be a #wrapper

Comment: Thanks John. I overlooked it

Answer (score 0):

For the left div, set the left margin. For the right div, set the right. Like this:

```
#leftDiv {
    margin-left: auto;
}

#rightDiv {
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

This puts them back to back in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works fine with `Zebra GC420d` Printer:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css"> 
    html, body { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    #div { min-height: 100%; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="border: 0px solid red;">
    <table border="0" width="100%" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
    <?php
    echo $name;
    ?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
    <?php
    echo 'https://goo.gl/2QvRXf';
    ?>
    </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Hope it helps !