# How to center two div put side by side

Tags: html, css

I have this situation http://jsfiddle.net/QrMn8/3/embedded/result/. Two divs put side by side, wrapped by a bigger div. What I want is to center the tables inside the two div. What can I do?

Comment: In what way do you want to center them? Horizontally? Vertically? Both?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357310/how-to-center-two-divs-floating-next-to-one-another

Comment: Horizontally. I want to set the X space on the left and right and X*2 among the two table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tables are inherently 100% of the width of the container.  So I set width: 291px; to the tables and boom no problems.  http://jsfiddle.net/QrMn8/6/embedded/result/

Comment: sorry had to change fiddle url

Answer (score 2):

You should use a container div. and use `margin:0 auto;` for that container div