# center two divs

Tags: html, css, centering

I have two `div`s which I want to center them.

Here is my code, that doesn't work:

HTML

```
<div id="central-top-wrapper" class="clearfix"> 
    //content
</div> 

<div id="central-bottom-wrapper" class="clearfix"> 
    //content 
</div>
```

CSS

```css
#central-top-wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}  
#central-bottom-wrapper {
    width: 43%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357310/how-to-center-two-divs-floating-next-to-one-another)

Comment: yes, but just a little

Comment: @user2013488 - [A little HTML5?](http://goo.gl/XFlkA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because you're floating them left.

Remove the float left attibute from each DIV and give them both "margin: 0 auto".

You also don't have to state display: block on the DIVs as that is their default state.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
<div id="central-top-wrapper">
    //divs content
</div>

<div id="central-bottom-wrapper">
    //divs content
</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#central-top-wrapper {width: 70%; margin: 0;}  
#central-bottom-wrapper {width: 43%; margin: 0;}
```